# Getting last field of a Path?

Tags: c#, string

I got the following string : "D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins\DashboardSimu" and I'd like to extract : "DashboardSimu"

Is there a simple way to get it ?

I know this is a beginner question but I don't manage to do it without for-loops and I'd be surprise there ain't any other way...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as followed

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("Your path");
```

then

```
String lastField = di.Name;
```

Comment: that one is exactly what I wanted !

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [System.IO.Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
using System.IO;

string lastComponent
    = Path.GetFileName(@"D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins\DashboardSimu");
// Now lastComponent is "DashBoardSimu".
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in one of the following ways

```
string folderName = new DirectoryInfo(@ "D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins\DashboardSimu").name;
```

or

```
string folderName = Path.GetFileName(@ "D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins\DashboardSimu");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = @"D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins\DashboardSimu";
string file = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

and similarly:

```
string dir = @"D:\Solutions\TestPlugin\Plugins", file = "DashboardSimu";
string path = Path.Combine(dir, file);
```